# VBA Code - Cell with Values in it returning Empty

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I had this code working as intended, unsure of what has changed.  I want this bit of code to look from G2:G1000 for the word Declined.  If it is declined then hide the row and color it red.  If that line is not Declined, then look from H2:H1000 for RETURN.  If it is RETURN then color it grey.  If not either, carry on.

The fun part of this one is that even though different lines have G and H with RETURN and Declined, the code is saying the cell is empty when it is clearly not.  Stepped through the code with F, and hovering over the if statement it states Sheet1.Range("G" & lCounter).Value = Empty.

```
Sub Format()
    Dim lCounter As Long
    For lCounter = 2 To 1000
        If Sheet1.Range("G" & lCounter).Value = "Declined" Then
            Range("A" & lCounter & ":S" & lCounter).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Rows(lCounter).Hidden = True 'Hides Row
        ElseIf Sheet1.Range("H" & lCounter).Value = "RETURN" Then
            Range("A" & lCounter & ":S" & lCounter).Interior.ColorIndex = 16
        Else
    End If
    Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please make sure that (1) your data is still on Sheet1 (not Sheet2, Sheet3 or some other), and (2) that this Sheet1 is the active sheet when you run the macro. Range() without a specified sheet refers to the active sheet and this can be a source of confusion. So always write Sheet1.Range(...) or set this sheet as active in start of macro `Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate`

Comment: @JohnSUN Sheet activation is not safe - active object can be changed at any moment, by user action, for example. So `Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets('Sheet1')` and further `sht1.Range(..)` is preferred.

Comment: @Akina To be fair, I also don't recommend using [**.Activate**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.activate(method)) (for any object, sheet or workbook or window) - that's what Microsoft recommends in the [**second example**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)#example)

Comment: Could you share example Data?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to update.  I did figure it out, though it seems like not in the best way.  I guess when I tested it out, the data was on Sheet1, and now the sheet is under a different name.  My solution, remove Sheet1 and it works as intended.

I believe there is an issue with resolving it as mentioned by @Akina because the macro lives in one work book, but needs to be used in another, just the nature of how the data is received.  Unless we were to copy and paste the data over, which would negate the steps taken here to mitigate the number of steps needed.